# Loop to generate table rows

Tags: php, html-table

I have a dynamic list of gym machines that are being pulled from a database.

I want to achieve this:

[image]

Right now I have 2 different pieces of code that I want to combine.

This pulls the machines from the database:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT m1.machine_id, m2.* FROM userPlanDetail AS m1 LEFT JOIN machines AS m2 ON     m1.machine_id = m2.machine_id WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1' AND `cardio` = 0";
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
$array = array();
```

This code creates the pictures:

```
<?php
    $machine_id = 1;
    $count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `userPlanDetail` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1'"), 0);
    $sql = "SELECT m1.machine_id, m2.* FROM userPlanDetail AS m1 LEFT JOIN machines AS m2 ON m1.machine_id = m2.machine_id WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
        $('<div/>', {
                'id': 'div _<?php echo $row["machine_id"]; ?>',
                'class': 'some_class_name',
                'html': '<img src="client workout page/round_<?php echo $machine_id++ ?>.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;">'+
                        '<img src="<?php echo $row["picture"]; ?>" style="width:200px;height:200px;display:block;margin:20px auto;"/> '+
                       ' <a class="demo" href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>" rel="group1"><img src="client workout page/click to play video.jpg" style="width:186px;height: 14px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></a>'+
                       ' <img src="" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:-15px;bottom:0;margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;">'
            }).appendTo('.body1');
<?php   }

 ?>
```

And this code generates the sets and reps:

```
$machine_atts = array(
'bicep curl' => array( 'sets' => 1, 'reps' => 50, 'weight' => 25 ),
'cable chest press' => array( 'sets' => 1, 'reps' => 100, 'weight' => 40 ),
'lat pulldown' => array( 'sets' => 2, 'reps' => 25, 'weight' => 20 ),
'tricep extension' => array( 'sets' => 3, 'reps' => 25, 'weight' => 30 ),
);

$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $i++;
  $sets = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['sets'];
  $reps = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['reps'];
  $weight = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['weight'];
$array[] = '<td>'.$row['machine_name'].' <span class="blue">#'.$i.'</span><br>sets <span class="blue">'.$sets.'</span> reps <span class="blue">'.$reps.'</span><br>weight <span class="blue">'.$weight.'</span></td>';
}
```

This goes wherever I want the sets and reps to be displayed:

```
echo '<table style="width: 100%; height:85%;table-layout:fixed;text-align:center;">';
  foreach ( array_chunk( $array, 1 ) as $chunk )
    echo '<tr>' . implode('', $chunk ) . '</tr>';
  echo '</table>';
```

I want to combine these separate pieces of code somehow to produce the output in the picture. Right now the pictures are fine but the sets and reps are being generated in a separate table.

Comment: Right now you are basically asking us to write that code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried editing the array to add the number and machine picture in there along with the sets and reps

Answer (score 0):

In the picture code fragment: create an associative array with whatever key you need to match teh machines to the sets/reps and send it to the sets/reps code fragment. There you can access the pictures.